# Unable to get realtime updates for 1 of my apps

Tags: facebook, subscriptions

I just finished implementing realtime updates for 1 of the 2 apps I am working on. it worked fine for the first app but the second app doesn't call my server when I make a purchase, I am able to test the call successfully from the realtime updates tab in facebook, I am also able to manually make a post request and have it respond, I just can't get facebook to call the server when I make a purchase.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my app, it took Facebook 24 hours to update for some reason. If you're URL doesn't work, test it locally to see if Facebook sends a post request. Create a new app and inside the URI use something like [Ngrok](http://ngrok.com) or [LocalTunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) and check if this works.

Another idea would be to remove all the fields you are listening for, and just add the "feed" option. That worked when debugging another app.